# Performing data manipulations on large records causes undefined behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a dateset which contains about 35,000 records and it's in JSON array format.

Now, I import it to my program like below,

```
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
const fs = require('fs');
let rawSample = jsonfile.readFileSync("./raw_sample.json");
```

Then I iterate, preform manipulations and save it like below,

```
rawSample.forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.input.forEach(function (element, item) {
                if (isUnicode(element)) {
                    rawSample[index].input.splice(item, 1);
                    // Check if Input Array is Empty then remove the Index
                    if (!rawSample[index].input.length) {
                        rawSample.splice(index, 1);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
    })
})

jsonfile.writeFileSync("./test-sample.json", rawSample);
```

Now, What happen is there are still elements with Unicode char on `test-sample.json` but if I run the above code by setting raw sample it self to `test-sample.json` it start to remove remaining items but I have to try like 5-6 times to completely remove everything.

I'm unsure why this happening. I did everything I could to debug but no luck so far.

Comment: Splicing stuff out when `forEach`ing over the same array is a recipe for disaster. Push results onto a new array or iterate in reverse. BTW, technically the behavior is defined, it's just not what you expected.

Comment: Another approach is to loop backwards with a regular for loop, if you think creating another array will be too memory intensive

Comment: Thanks it works..